# Auth not working for SharePoint hosted Apps. Fiddler fixes Issue?

Tags: authentication, app

I've setup the whole SharePoint 2013 App Domain stuff many times on different configurations without issues, but now I have one customer installation with some weird behaviour.

If I start an App installed in the hostweb, I get the credentials Dialog for Authentication. I'd expect automatic Authentication. I tried quite a bit, but to no success. Yesterday I found an interesting solution to it. As long as Fiddler is running on my Client, Authentication works as expected.

What does Fiddler do? Any ideas what causes that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing authentication for the "catchall/app" web from negotiate to NTLM. I´m still not sure what fiddler does so it works, but at least apps work as expected. An error in chrome "Invalid Auth Credentials" pointed me in the right direction.